# Python/Django - Data does not appear from fetch request in template

Tags: python, django, api, django-templates

I am new to python and am trying to pull data from an imported news api, however, even though I am getting no visible error it does not appear to be showing up in the template. I'm trying to a MVC framework to organize my code

Starting with `views.py`

from **future** import unicode_literals

```
import json
import logging
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from newsapi import NewsApiClient

from .forms import UserProfileCreationForm
from .models import Animals

def news_list(request):
    newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='123')
    all_articles = newsapi.get_everything(
    q='animals',
    sources='bbc-news,national-geographic, new-scientist, reddit-r-all',
    from_param='2018-09-29',
    to='2018-09-22',
    language='en',
    sort_by='relevancy')['articles']
    context = {'articles': all_articles,
           'type': str(type(all_articles)),
           'name': 'Someone'}

    template = loader.get_template('home.html')

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Then `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.news_list, name="news_list"),
]
```

Here is also `urls.py` from the project folder, not sure if it is helpful or not

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
   url(r'^users/', include('dangerzone.urls')),
   url(r'^users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

And lastly the templates

`base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
     {% block title %}
      Python App
     {% endblock title %}
    </title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <main>
     {% block content %}

     {% endblock content %}
    </main>
   </body>
  </html>
```

`home.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block content %}

   <h2>Latest News</h2>
    <ul>
     {% for article in articles %}
      <li>{{ article.source }}</li>
      <li>{{ article.author }}</li>
      <li>{{ article.title }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
 {% endblock content %}
```

If more information is needed please let me know.

So far I have tried:

1. Changing the url address from `r'^$'` to just `''`
2. Importing without the HttpResponse like so:

   ```
    def news_list(request):
        newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='123')
        all_articles = newsapi.get_everything(
             q='animals',
             sources='bbc-news,national-geographic, new-scientist, reddit-r-all',
             from_param='2018-09-29',to='2018-09-22',
             language='en',
             sort_by='relevancy',
             page=2)['articles']
       return render(request, 'home.html', {'articles' : all_articles})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us your Python/Django versions?

Also, if I'm not mistaken, your

```
template = loader.get_template('home.html')

return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

is outside your **`news_list()`** function.

Comment: hi I'm using python3.7

Answer (score 0):

Does all_articles return something at least ?

If not it may come from your API.

Also you can add your variable a lot quicker with locals()

```py
return render(request, 'home.html', locals())
```